# MySQL : why is left join slower then inner join? Optimization help required

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

I have a MySQL query which joins between the two table. I need to map call id from first table with second table. Second table may not have the call id, hence I need to left join the tables. Below is the query, it takes around 125 seconds to finish.

```
select uniqueid, TRANTAB.DISP, TRANTAB.DIAL FROM
closer_log LEFT JOIN
(select call_uniqueId, sum(dispo_duration) as DISP, sum(dialing_duration) as DIAL
        from agent_transition_log  group by call_uniqueId) TRANTAB
on closer_log.uniqueid=TRANTAB.call_uniqueId;
```

Here is the explain output of the query with left join.

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+----------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type  | possible_keys | key                        | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+----------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | closer_log           | index | NULL          | uniqueid                   | 43      | NULL |  37409 | Using index |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>           | ALL   | NULL          | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL |  32535 |             |
|  2 | DERIVED     | agent_transition_log | index | NULL          | index_agent_transition_log | 43      | NULL | 159406 |             |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+----------------------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

If I do the internal join, then execution time is around 2 seconds.

```
select uniqueid, TRANTAB.DISP, TRANTAB.DIAL FROM
closer_log JOIN
(select call_uniqueId, sum(dispo_duration) as DISP, sum(dialing_duration) as DIAL
        from agent_transition_log  group by call_uniqueId) TRANTAB
on closer_log.uniqueid=TRANTAB.call_uniqueId;
```

Explain output of query with internal join.

```
    +----+-------------+----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type  | possible_keys                      | key                        | key_len | ref                   | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>           | ALL   | NULL                               | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL                  |  32535 |                          |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | closer_log  | ref   | uniqueid,index_closer_log | index_closer_log  | 43      | TRANTAB.call_uniqueId |      1 | Using where; Using index |
|  2 | DERIVED     | agent_transition_log | index | NULL                               | index_agent_transition_log | 43      | NULL                  | 159406 |                          |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+--------------------------+
```

My question is, why is internal join so much faster then left join. Does my query has any logical fault which is causing the slow execution? What are my optimization options. The call ids in both the tables are indexed.

**Edit 1)** Added table descriptions

```
mysql> desc agent_transition_log;
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field              | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_log_id        | int(9) unsigned      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| event_time         | datetime             | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dispoStatus        | varchar(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| call_uniqueId      | varchar(40)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| xfer_call_uid      | varchar(40)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pause_duration     | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| wait_duration      | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| dialing_duration   | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| ring_wait_duration | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| talk_duration      | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| dispo_duration     | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| park_duration      | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| rec_duration       | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| xfer_wait_duration | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| logged_in_duration | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| sub_status         | varchar(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc closer_log;
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| closecallid    | int(9) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| lead_id        | int(9) unsigned      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| list_id        | bigint(14) unsigned  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| campaign_id    | varchar(20)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| call_date      | datetime             | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_epoch    | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_epoch      | int(10) unsigned     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| length_in_sec  | int(10)              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status         | varchar(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone_code     | varchar(10)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone_number   | varchar(18)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user           | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comments       | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| processed      | enum('Y','N')        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| queue_seconds  | decimal(7,2)         | YES  |     | 0.00    |                |
| user_group     | varchar(20)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| xfercallid     | int(9) unsigned      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| uniqueid       | varchar(40)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| callerid       | varchar(40)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| agent_only     | varchar(20)          | YES  |     |         |                |
| queue_position | smallint(4) unsigned | YES  |     | 1       |                |
| root_uid       | varchar(40)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_uid     | varchar(40)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| extension      | varchar(100)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| alt_dial       | varchar(6)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| talk_duration  | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| did_pattern    | varchar(50)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Both queries are the same, you forgot to paste your inner join. Could you provide original tables also?

Comment: Since the inner join is so much faster, have you tried `UNION`ing it with `closer_log` rows that have no corresponding `agent_transition_log`?

Comment: looks like your closer_log doesn't have an index on uniqueid? that makes both queries slower

Comment: @Ashalynd closer_log does have index, please verify the table description that I added.

Comment: please post SHOW CREATE TABLE closer_log and SHOW CREATE TABLE agent_transition_log, these commands give more information about the table structure including the indexes definitions.

Comment: Posting output of SHOW CREATE TABLE soon. Indexes are created anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Left join looks for the fields from left + unmatched entries from right, so it has to check every joined field in the right table which might be NULL (if you don't have an index on the fields for that JOIN, it means the query will check the whole right table every time). Inner join looks only for direct matches, so it might not have to go over the whole table to perform a join (Especially if you join on indexed fields).

By the way, if you only want to display the entries mentioned in agent_transition_log, you don't need join at all:

```
select call_uniqueId, sum(dispo_duration) as DISP, sum(dialing_duration) as DIAL
from agent_transition_log  group by call_uniqueId;
```

will do the job.

OR if you do want to add the missing entries:

```
SELECT call_uniqueId, sum(dispo_duration) as DISP, sum(dialing_duration) as DIAL
from agent_transition_log  group by call_uniqueId
UNION
SELECT uniqueid as call_uniqueid, NULL as DISP, NULL as DIAL from closer_log
WHERE uniqueid not in (SELECT call_uniqueid FROM agent_transition_log);
```

Comment: I understand your point. So we are talking that my derived table does not have an index, hence the performance problem. Is there a way to add index to the derived table?

Comment: No, you have to add the indexes to your original tables. Also, could you just post SHOW CREATE TABLE for your tables? The view you posted doesn't say enough about what kind of indexes you have. Also, what about your agent_transition_log, does it have the index on call_uniqueId (the grouping field)?

Comment: Posting output of SHOW CREATE TABLE soon. Indexes are created anyway.

Comment: Do you actually need to output the entries which aren't mentioned in agent_transition_log?